# Matrix powers sequence bounded

Tags: matrices, analysis

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}^*$ and $A\in\mathcal{M}_m(\mathbb{C})$ such that the matrix sequence $(A^n)_{n\geq 0}$ is bounded. Is the sequence $(\|A\|^n)_{n \geq 0}$ bounded ?

Comment: How do you define a matrix sequence as bounded?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: The definition  is: There existe a real constant $M$ st for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have : $\|A^n\| \leq M $.

Comment: @copper.hat Actually, the problem is about $\|A\|^n$, which really means we need to show that if $\|A^n\|$ is bounded then $\|A\|\leq 1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I misunderstood the question. I didn't notice that the power was inside and thought the question was trivial.

Comment: @copper.hat Neither did I at first :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not need to be. Take
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & 1 \\ 0 & \alpha\end{bmatrix}, \qquad 0<\alpha<1.
$$
Then $A^n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and hence $(\|A^n\|_2)_{n\geq 0}$ is bounded, while $\|A\|_2>1$ and hence $\|A\|^n_2\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Even simpler, use $A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\|A\|_2 = 2$, $A^2 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you Algebraic Pavel and copper.hat for these counter-examples.